# Firebase - Display to ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have data stored on firebase which has a film id as the child and within it contains the film name. I want to display the film names stored on firebase within a ListView. The problem I am having is that I am unsure how to get only the data of the film name rather than all the data including the user. I am also uploading the data from one activity and want to display it in another activity within the ListView.

[image: Firebase Database]

[image: How it currently displays]

**Upload to Firebase**

```
String filmID = filmDetails.getString("film_id");
String filmName = filmDetails.getString("film_name");
DatabaseReference currentUserDBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);

if (currentUserID != null) {

currentUserDBR.orderByChild(filmID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String fbFilmID = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        if (fbFilmID.contains(filmID)) { // If film already exists Remove it on click
            btnSaved.setText("Add to List");
            currentUserDBR.child(filmID).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed from Films List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else { // If film does not exist add it on click
            btnSaved.setText("Remove");
            currentUserDBR.child(filmID).child("Film Name").setValue(filmName);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved to Films List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    }
```

**Display to ListView**

```
DatabaseReference filmsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Users");
lvSavedFilms = findViewById(R.id.lv_display_saved_films);
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listitem, R.id.lv_text_color, filmName);
lvSavedFilms.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

ChildEventListener childEventListener = filmsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
/*                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
                };
                HashMap<String, Object> hmFilmName = snapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);*/
                String value = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                filmName.add(value);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(filmName.indexOf(snapshot.getValue(String.class))));
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

I tried `String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);` but I got an error saying it couldnt convert HashMap to String.

Comment: You shared two complete listeners here. Which one is showing the output in your second screenshot?

Comment: These lines: ```String value = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                filmName.add(value);``` in the "Display to Listview" code are doing the output within the 2nd image

Comment: In that case, what is `filmsReference`?

Comment: My bad I missed that out I've added it now. It's this: ```DatabaseReference filmsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Users");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `filmsReference` points to the `Users` node in your database, the `snapshot` that you get in `onChildAdded` contains all data for the `nfx...` node.

To get to the actual film node, you have to loop over the child nodes of `snapshot:

```
filmsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        for (DataSnapshot filmSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value = filmSnapshot.child("Film Name").getValue(String.class);
            filmName.add(value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That was a copy/paste/forgot-to-modify :)